# What is the proper name for the "second ratio" of a prime number (meaning the second difference / second sum)?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, ratio, prime-gaps

I became interested in the second differences of prime numbers, and as part of my amateur investigations, I wanted simple metric that would allow me to directly compare prime number sequences across the whole spectrum of prime number scales.

The second ratio is the difference of the two gaps surrounding a prime number divided by the sum of those two gaps. I visualize it as every odd prime number being at a specific position within a 1 dimensional box defined by the next prime number and the previous prime number. The second difference is the absolute position in the box, whereas the second ratio is its relative position, normalizing the box around each prime number to 1.

To this end, I started to use a relation which I call a "Second Ratio". My main question is how would I look up the state of research on grouping primes by second ratios? Mostly, I expect there's name for this that I don't know.

After dabbling in this question for several years (including getting these accepted: https://oeis.org/A295746 & https://oeis.org/A295973 ) I would like to understand other approaches to similar questions. Some gentle tips on prerequisites would not be out of place. Thank you.

*The following is an example of a graph of the dataset, using the **second ratio** (between -1 and 1) of a 100000 1024-bit prime numbers. Positive second ratios are on the right side of the circle, negative on the left. The length of the radiating lines are proportional to the frequency of that **sr** in the dataset. Only the most common are labeled. Many low frequency **sr** fill in the gaps between the more common.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the second ratio of the $n$-th prime number $p_n$ equals
$$\frac{(p_{n+1}-p_n)-(p_n-p_{n-1})}{p_{n+1}-p_{n-1}}.$$
Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. I've been thinking of it as the gaps added together, but that clearly equals the the next prime minus the prev prime. So yeah. Is it really called the second ratio? Are there papers on patterns observed comparing sequences of consecutive primes?

Comment: I'm just calling it the second ratio because that's what you called it. I have never read or thought about this before.

Comment: I think that a pattern concerning this ratio (should it exist for a smaller range) will eventually vanish as all patterns that yet have been discovered concerning prime gaps.

Comment: Many people heavily disagree when they hear "primes are random" with the argument that the prime numbers are clearly determined. This is actually true, but the sequence of prime gaps is , according to all we currently know , utterly chaotic and cannot be predicted in ranges that have not yet been checked.

Comment: If we want to find a new prime with, say , $100$ digits magnitude , we have no better method than sieving out small factors and testing the remaining candidates. We cannot predict where the next prime is and how the sequence of prime gaps will continue.

Comment: My interest isn't about finding unknown primes. I think of it as mapping the prime number neighborhoods with the second differences and the second ratios as attributes of the primes. From my (admittedly naive) perspective, there are relations between primes that have the same second difference. For example, all prime numbers with a second difference of zero (which is always a common one) are surrounded by gaps which have a factor of 3 (other than 5). My question is still, has anyone else looked at anything about how the second ratio is related to anything?

Comment: The second ratios that are most common (1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 0, ) as far as I can tell, stay the most common ratios for as large as I've been able to calculate (my older mac bogs down pretty severely by the time I'm over 6000 bit primes). One of my interests is determining if I have a dataset with a representative range of second differences and ratios, and the symmetry of the graphs I'm making show a broad estimate of that at a glance.